# CSS mix-blend-mode chrome issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I need to make an effect like Photoshop overlay. My code work fine in Firefox but it doesn't work in chrome.
There's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfnrdday/1/)

There's my code:

HTML

`<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-h-c-614-631-5.jpg"/>
<div id="blend"></div>`

CSS:

`img{
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}`

`#blend{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    z-index:100;
    background-color:#fff;
    mix-blend-mode:overlay;
}`

Answer (score 2):

The lastes Chrome 40.x doesn't come with the `mix-blend-mode` feature enabled.

You can enable it manually in Chrome or Opera:

1. Copy and paste
   **chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features** into the
   address bar, then press enter.
2. Click the ‘Enable’ link within that section.
3. Click the ‘Relaunch Now’ button at the bottom of the browser window.

Having said that you should know that mix-blend-mode will only work on clients with enabled expirimental features. :(

I, myself, was pretty dissapointed to find this out.

The `background-blend-mode: overlay;` feature is available without it.

It will blend `background-image` against the `background-color` . No, you can't cheat by making the color transparent.

Hopefully, we'll see `mix-blend-mode` ship with chrome by default soon.

Comment: Thank you but I know this way. But I want know if there is a method to obtain the same result with canvas or SVG